# How to setup a hamburger type menu using CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, slider

How do I setup a html/css page that has a hamburger menu? Below I have a screen shots of a site where this was done.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The hamburger menu appears automatically when you're using bootstrap to layout your pages. Try this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/ and shrink the browser window, you'll see the hamburger menu appear when you make the window smaller.

Here is a tutorial on Responsive web design:  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Here is some information on how to get the hamburger menu otherwise:
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_menu-hamburger